# Do I need to using subscription or consumable IAP on Apple

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

if i was selling 1 month memberships in an app Apple says you should use Non-Renewing Subscriptions as youre giving access to your service for a fixed amount of time.

Ok fine...

But what if you wanted to allow users to purchase multiple '1 month subscriptions' ?

So each time they purchased the membership IAP it would add 1 month to there membership...

This would work if the IAP was set up as a consumable.... you just process the IAP and add a month to their membership, but would it work using 'Non-Renewing Subscriptions' ??  As i am assuming once you buy a Non-Renewing Subscriptions you have wait till it expires before you can buy again?

Comment: There is no reason you can't use an auto renewing subscription,  it if you do use a non renewing subscription then it is up to you to track the expiration date. If the user purchased multiple months you would extend the expiration date each time they purchase a month

Comment: As long as you prevent the user from buying the subscription multiple times, you can use auto-renewing subscriptions as mentioned by @Paulw11. When you insist on "the user needs to buy a 1 month subscription again and again" then you need to use consumables or non-renewing subscriptions. But, then you need to handle expiration and user with multiple devices yourself. Here is a tutorial on non-renewing subscriptions: https://www.raywenderlich.com/754-in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscriptions-tutorial